# Create JWT (Json Web Token) with RSA encryption using Java library

Tags: java, jwt

I am looking to develop a JWT app with RSA encryption using "Nimbus JOSE+JWT" library. I am seeking sample code.

I would like to use the following Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
    <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>3.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Note: Please always use the latest version from Maven Central repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the latest version of 4.23 of 'Nimbus Jose JWT' then there is some minor changes in the API.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
    <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>4.23</version>
</dependency>
```

I've shown the code below for reference:

```
public class JwtJoseExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator;
        try {
            keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");

            keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024);

            // generate the key pair
            KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();

            // create KeyFactory and RSA Keys Specs
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            RSAPublicKeySpec publicKeySpec = keyFactory.getKeySpec(keyPair.getPublic(), RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
            RSAPrivateKeySpec privateKeySpec = keyFactory.getKeySpec(keyPair.getPrivate(), RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);

            // generate (and retrieve) RSA Keys from the KeyFactory using Keys Specs
            RSAPublicKey publicRsaKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
            RSAPrivateKey privateRsaKey  = (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

            JWTClaimsSet.Builder claimsSet = new JWTClaimsSet.Builder();
            claimsSet.issuer("https://my-auth-server.com");
            claimsSet.subject("John Kerr");
            claimsSet.audience(getAudience());
            claimsSet.expirationTime(new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1000*60*10));
            claimsSet.notBeforeTime(new Date());
            claimsSet.jwtID(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

            System.out.println("--------------------------");
            System.out.println("Claim Set : \n"+claimsSet.build());

            // create the JWT header and specify:
            //  RSA-OAEP as the encryption algorithm
            //  128-bit AES/GCM as the encryption method
            JWEHeader header = new JWEHeader(JWEAlgorithm.RSA_OAEP, EncryptionMethod.A128GCM);

            // create the EncryptedJWT object
            EncryptedJWT jwt = new EncryptedJWT(header, claimsSet.build());

            // create an RSA encrypter with the specified public RSA key
            RSAEncrypter encrypter = new RSAEncrypter(publicRsaKey);

            // do the actual encryption
            jwt.encrypt(encrypter);

            // serialize to JWT compact form
            String jwtString = jwt.serialize();
            System.out.println("\nJwt Compact Form : "+jwtString);

            // in order to read back the data from the token using your private RSA key:
            // parse the JWT text string using EncryptedJWT object
            jwt = EncryptedJWT.parse(jwtString);

            // create a decrypter with the specified private RSA key
            RSADecrypter decrypter = new RSADecrypter(privateRsaKey);

            // do the decryption
            jwt.decrypt(decrypter);

            // print out the claims

            System.out.println("===========================================================");
            System.out.println("Issuer: [ " + jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getIssuer() + "]");
            System.out.println("Subject: [" + jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getSubject()+ "]");
            System.out.println("Audience size: [" + jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getAudience().size()+ "]");
            System.out.println("Expiration Time: [" + jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getExpirationTime()+ "]");
            System.out.println("Not Before Time: [" + jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getNotBeforeTime()+ "]");
            System.out.println("Issue At: [" + jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getIssueTime()+ "]");
            System.out.println("JWT ID: [" + jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getJWTID()+ "]");
            System.out.println("===========================================================");

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | JOSEException | ParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static List<String> getAudience(){
        List<String> audience = new ArrayList<>();
        audience.add("https://my-web-app.com");
        audience.add("https://your-web-app.com");
        return audience;
    }
}
```

### The output is:

Claim Set :

```
{"sub":"John Kerr","aud":["https:\/\/my-web-app.com","https:\/\/your-web-app.com"],"nbf":1471116052,"iss":"https:\/\/my-auth-server.com","exp":1471116652,"jti":"8769fc6d-b69f-45e3-b1a5-52695c23675e"}
```

Jwt Compact Form :

```
eyJlbmMiOiJBMTI4R0NNIiwiYWxnIjoiUlNBLU9BRVAifQ.f2ZZyMaJi03RqunyWsLvIr7tNX1KvTRUcpN9qsBHvbXIouZCyepQMsbI1v88GHuLIV3f6SviCDyICp7kZCj_9q-yIi_dIuroADWQ-P_UnqNPRXQ1yEwbmrLUK80lBtKyc3Z6g_3Db_HLtD6QPEq-zUAh3wJ7uSPxhql2oc9otGc.Xbyrf4iWM0shNp4S.TCKoJGAEQ4rpJJk2qZP11awxTEWTg-r5VpppGgZNhiHCBhnGnyR2sb86O7ISc3j-i4OYp7Xl2vThzztD1ojy_IKPYQkg_iACuo6yjzdopQQT143vjYuFLfFhQFfjfCoO6iibTqK7vmqfF0bUWD6Nj-4MwjlW6dFV7mNQEN50dkiMrFMZkmiVKZRa50jOK1NcoWYiKSrCOQduJYibJfF6jSQARX9MsX5tib-3BXSsKtPLNrQ6mFfvDzzruBuO4gKWLE3PQPUfIQ.gXt5KcpxEbfYLP854GvcQw
===========================================================
Issuer: [ https://my-auth-server.com]
Subject: [John Kerr]
Audience size: [2]
Expiration Time: [Sun Aug 14 01:00:52 IST 2016]
Not Before Time: [Sun Aug 14 00:50:52 IST 2016]
Issue At: [null]
JWT ID: [8769fc6d-b69f-45e3-b1a5-52695c23675e]
===========================================================
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//This is a complete encryption and decryption module using 
//Algorithm: JWEAlgorithm.RSA_OAEP_256
//Encryption Method: A128CBC_HS256

public static String  encrypt(String text) throws Exception {
    // Set the plain text
    Payload payload = new Payload(text);
    // Create the header
    JWEHeader header = new JWEHeader(JWEAlgorithm.RSA_OAEP_256, EncryptionMethod.A128CBC_HS256);
    // Create the JWE object and encrypt it
    JWEObject jweObject = new JWEObject(header, payload);
    jweObject.encrypt(new RSAEncrypter(getPublicKey()));
    // Serialise to compact JOSE form...
    String jweString = jweObject.serialize();
    LOG.info("Generated Encrypted Key : {}", jweString);
    return jweString;
}

public static String decrypt(String text) throws Exception {
    // Parse into JWE object...
    JWEObject jweObject = JWEObject.parse(text);
    jweObject.decrypt(new RSADecrypter(getPrivateKey()));
    // Get the plain text
    Payload payload = jweObject.getPayload();
    System.out.println(payload.toString());
    return payload.toString();
}

private static RSAPublicKey getPublicKey() throws Exception {
    String filename = "/home/vaibhav/Setups/cert/pub.der";
    File f = new File(filename);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int)f.length()];
    dis.readFully(keyBytes);
    dis.close();

    X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return (RSAPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(spec);
}

private static RSAPrivateKey getPrivateKey() throws Exception {
    String filename = "/home/vaibhav/Setups/cert/private.pkcs8";
    File f = new File(filename);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int)f.length()];
    dis.readFully(keyBytes);
    dis.close();

    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec1 = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return (RSAPrivateKey) kf.generatePrivate(spec1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the code to use "nimbus-jose-jwt" library, please find the code below

```java
JWTClaimsSet jwtClaims = new JWTClaimsSet();
jwtClaims.setIssuer(ISSUER);
jwtClaims.setSubject(SUBJECT);

List<String> aud = new ArrayList<String>();
aud.add("https://app-one.com");
aud.add("https://app-two.com");

jwtClaims.setAudience(aud);
// Set expiration in 10 minutes
jwtClaims.setExpirationTime(new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1000*60*10));
jwtClaims.setNotBeforeTime(new Date());
jwtClaims.setIssueTime(new Date());
jwtClaims.setJWTID(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

System.out.println("=========== JWT CLAMINS =============");
System.out.println(jwtClaims.toJSONObject());


// Request JWT encrypted with RSA-OAEP and 128-bit AES/GCM
JWEHeader header = new JWEHeader(JWEAlgorithm.RSA_OAEP, EncryptionMethod.A128GCM);

// Create the encrypted JWT object
EncryptedJWT jwt = new EncryptedJWT(header, jwtClaims);


// Create an encrypter with the specified public RSA key
RSAEncrypter encrypter = new RSAEncrypter(publicKey);
jwt.encrypt(encrypter);

String jwtString = jwt.serialize();

System.out.println(jwtString);


// Parse back
jwt = EncryptedJWT.parse(jwtString);

// Create a decrypter with the specified private RSA key
RSADecrypter decrypter = new RSADecrypter(privateKey);

// Decrypt
jwt.decrypt(decrypter);

// Retrieve JWT claims
System.out.println(jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getIssuer());;
System.out.println(jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getSubject());
System.out.println(jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getAudience().size());
System.out.println(jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getExpirationTime());
System.out.println(jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getNotBeforeTime());
System.out.println(jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getIssueTime());
System.out.println(jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getJWTID());
```

This code has also use the public and private keys to create JWT token, also you will need those keys to extract claims and validate it.

Once you run this code, you should be able to see following jwtClaims:

```json
{
    "exp": 1429126207,
    "sub": "alice",
    "nbf": 1429125607,
    "aud": [
          "https://app-one.com",
          "https://app-two.com"
    ],
    "iss": "A FaceBook Cooperation",    
    "jti": "5c94d2db-e818-4746-b2f2-a4cd084d5a44",
    "iat": 1429125607
}
```